# jspm install github repository to specific folder

Tags: jspm

I am trying to install a github repo using

jspm install myPackageName = github:owner/repo@master

Which works fine but it creates folder under jspm packages with owner_name\repo_name.

Is there any way I can override that behaviour so that it places the library directly under repo_name removing the owner_name.

Answer (score 2):

`jspm install repo=github:owner/repo@master` will add a jspm mapping as `repo`.

Then, depending on where you are importing to:

ES6:

`import 'repo';`

Typescript:

`import * as repo from 'repo';`

Within a `<script>` tag:

`SystemJS.import('repo');`